# Colocar un div dentro de otro hacia la derecha

Tags: css, flexbox, flex

[Lo que busco](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Oiq5.png)

Hola a todos, estoy comenzando con el desarrollo web y comencé a utilizar el display flex. Sin embargo, a pesar de los diferentes intentos que realicé, no consigo el poder separar el cuadro negro  hacia la derecha y dejar el resto de elementos hacia la izquierda.

Todo  lo estoy colocando dentro de un div llamado "Header" y solo el cuadro negro es lo que estoy buscando la forma de moverlo hacia la derecha, si me pudieran ayudar lo agradecería muchísimo.

```
.header{
    background-color:#F5F8DF ;
    display: flex;
    height: 60px;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw; 
}
.header__button{
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #F5F8DF;
    width: 10em;
    height: 60px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transform: skew(-15deg);
    border: 2px solid green;
    color: black;
    transition: .3s;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 53px;
    z-index: 1;
      
    }
.header__button:hover{
    background-color: #198026;
    width: 11em;
    color:white;
    transition: .3s;
}
.prueba {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #000;
}
```

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </link>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#2A2929">
  <nav>
  <div class="header">
    <a href="index.html">
      <div class="logo">
        <div class="logoimg">
          <img src="img/chuekimg.png" width="60" height="60">
        </div>
        <div class="txtlogo">
          <img src="img/txt.png" width="140" height="70">
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="header__button">
      <span>DOTA 2 </span>
    </div>
    <div class="header__button">
      <span>CS:GO </span>
    </div>   
    <div class="prueba">   
    </div>
  </div>
  </nav> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aplicando el estilo `margin-left: auto` en tu contenedor de clase `prueba` conseguirás el efecto que buscas (en el ejemplo no se ven las imágenes porque no están añadidas):

```css
.header{
    background-color:#F5F8DF ;
    display: flex;
    height: 60px;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw; 
}
.header__button{
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #F5F8DF;
    width: 10em;
    height: 60px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transform: skew(-15deg);
    border: 2px solid green;
    color: black;
    transition: .3s;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 53px;
    z-index: 1;
      
    }
.header__button:hover{
    background-color: #198026;
    width: 11em;
    color:white;
    transition: .3s;
}
.prueba {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #000;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </link>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#2A2929">
  <nav>
  <div class="header">
    <a href="index.html">
      <div class="logo">
        <div class="logoimg">
          <img src="img/chuekimg.png" width="60" height="60">
        </div>
        <div class="txtlogo">
          <img src="img/txt.png" width="140" height="70">
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="header__button">
      <span>DOTA 2 </span>
    </div>
    <div class="header__button">
      <span>CS:GO </span>
    </div>   
    <div class="prueba">   
    </div>
  </div>
  </nav> 
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que consigues añadiendo esto es que los bloques previos a donde pones `margin-left:auto` queden alineados a la izquierda, y el contenedor donde se aplica este estilo, y los siguientes, alineados a la derecha.

Espero que te pueda servir

Answer (score 0):

La manera en que Flex funciona, es que al declarar un DIV como `display: flex`, sus elementos hijos directos se convierten en FLEX. Por la manera en que tienes ordenado tu código, en realidad estás volviendo Flex es a tu primer link (`<a></a>`), a tus dos botones (Dota y CS GO) y al div con class="prueba" (el rectángulo negro).

Entendiendo esto, a pesar de que se puede, es más trabajoso ir justificando cada uno de los elementos con `justify-self`. La solución más rápida y sencilla sería envolver todos tus elementos que van a la izquierda dentro de un div y luego enviar el primer bloque a la izquierda y el segundo a la derecha usando en css [justify-content: space-between](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content), tu HTML quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </link>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#2A2929">
  <nav>
  <div class="header">
    <div>
      <a href="index.html">
        <div class="logo">
          <div class="logoimg">
            <img src="img/chuekimg.png" width="60" height="60">
          </div>
          <div class="txtlogo">
            <img src="img/txt.png" width="140" height="70">
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="header__button">
      <span>DOTA 2 </span>
    </div>
    <div class="header__button">
      <span>CS:GO </span>
    </div>   
    <div class="prueba">   
    </div>
  </div>
  </nav> 
</body>
</html>
```

Y luego en tu css ve hasta .header y haz lo siguiente:

```css
.header{
    background-color:#F5F8DF ;
    display: flex;
    height: 60px;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100vw;
    justify-content: space-between
}
```

### Explicación:

Para que entiendas cómo funciona, básicamente lo que estás haciendo al encerrar tus elementos en ese nuevo div, es que ahora los elementos hijos directos de tu div "header" serían únicamente tu nuevo div y el div del rectángulo negro, por lo que al usar `justify-content: space-between`, estás separando tus elementos flex hacia las esquinas de la pantalla.

Espero que te haya servido, cualquier duda estoy atento.